# Use an external .jpg image in a gallery modal based on CSS & JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

First time post on here, so give it my best shot.

My goal is to change the image gallery on my website. Right now, when an image is clicked, it opens in a new tab. I want to, instead, have the image open on the same page over the gallery. To do this, I have referred to a tutorial at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive_js). I've implemented it on my site and it works well (on my PC, not live on the net yet). My issue is that it pulls the image for the overlay/modal from the thumbnail image. Because my thumbnail images are low quality, I would like the modal to pull .jpg from an external file. Is there a way to modify the code to do this? I tried searching on here for a solution and changing the code myself...no solution. Here's some of the code, pretty much straight from w3schools.com.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   images[i].onclick = function(){
       modal.style.display = "block";
       modalImg.src = this.src;
       modalImg.alt = this.alt;
       captionText.innerHTML = this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
   }
}
</script>
```

If the code only needs a slight modification, then, that would be great. If it needs a complete overhaul to do what I would like it to, that's fine. I'll just scrap what I've changed on the site on my PC and look for a completely new solution. Here's the gallery on net I'm trying to change: [mygallery](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~mstingle/work/traditional/traditional.html).

Comment: It all depends on how your images are named. If, for example, your thumbnails were named like `img01.jpg` and your large images were named like `large-img01.jpg` you could just change `modalImg.src = this.src;` to `modalImg.src = 'large-' + this.src;`. If your files have entirely unrelated names it would be more difficult. Can you provide more details?

Comment: The external .jpgs I would like to use/refer to use various, random, names, like: coloredpencil-heads.jpg. I could rename them though. I'll be honest, I have no background with Javascript, so this is all a little new to me. All my previous coding is just in CSS & HTML. Is modalImg.src = this.src; to modalImg.src = 'large-' + this.src; the CSS I need to change?

Comment: No, it is a line in your javascript. Second line in your `images[i].onclick` function. Renaming the images so that they have a similar name to the thumbnail would definitely be the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the code to what you recommended in your first post. I also changed a .jpg name to "large-traditional001.jpg" to match the corresponding thumbnail "traditional001.jpg" as a test. Still didn't work. Here is a sample of how an image is coded into the html:

Comment: <div class="img">
  <img src="../gallery_images/traditional/traditional001.jpg" alt="Golden Rectangle" width="420" height="420">
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your thumbnails and large images reside in the same folder and share some sensible naming convention such as:

Thumbnail: `img01.jpg`
Large version: `large-img01.jpg`

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   images[i].onclick = function(){
       modal.style.display = "block";

       /* Get the src of the clicked image. */
       var src = this.src;

       /* Get the filename and extension of the image */
       var filename = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

       /* Get the file path minus the filename */
       var filepath = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

       /* reconstruct your file path appending "large-" to the filename */
       modalImg.src = filepath + 'large-' + filename;
       modalImg.alt = this.alt;
       captionText.innerHTML = this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
   }
}
```

Obviously this would need to be modified to accommodate your own naming convention.